# Approved Facebook Messenger App is public while it's set to Development mode

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

In my App Review tab, I see "Your app is in development and unavailable to the public."

However, when people message my page, I receive the messages on my webhook, and they can click template messages and interact with the bot.

I don't intend for my app to be public yet. Has anyone else noticed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is fixing this Tuesday, May 24th.

"We have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed next Tuesday. Stay tuned." -Facebook Team